# How to programmatically destroy visual controls in delphi?

Tags: delphi, controls

I have a trouble.
I create a label object.

```
var lbl:Tlabel;
begin
lbl:=TLabel.Create(nil);
....
```

Ok, but after destroying it, it still remains on form.
There is my code:

```
lbl.free;
lbl := nil;
```

After executing it, controls stays on form.
There is a solution? I need to destroy this component, this should dissapear from form.
Thanks.

EDIT : RemoveControl(AControl: TControl); procedure isnt working.
EDIT2:

```
for I := 0 to 4 do begin
 lbl:=TLabel.Create(nil);
lbl.Top :=  100+z*i;
 lbl.Left := 88;
 Lbl.Width := 80;
  Lbl.Height := 14;
  lbl.Font.Size := 9;
 lbl.Caption := nm[i];
 Form1.InsertControl(lbl);
```

This control stays on form.

Comment: Don't you have another label under the destroyed one on your form ? This should work properly (and actually works).

Comment: Your `lbl` cannot remain on the form because it never appears on the form

Comment: @Serg, maybe that's what happens in that `....` part of the code...

Comment: @TLama - if so the question could be 'here is my code: `...`. it does not work. thanks.'

Comment: Free is enough. As always, show code the demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Destroying a control is no different from destroying any other object. Simply call Free on the object and you are done.

The only time that you run into problems is when you call Free on an object for whom an event handler is running. For example freeing a button in that button's OnClick handler. In such a scenario you need to post a message to your form, and then free the button when that queued message is processed.

Your problem is that you are calling Free on the wrong object. You created 5 labels but only held on to a reference to one of them. You need to free all 5 labels. You'll want an array or a list to hold the label references. Then you'll be able to free them all.

In your form declare an array:

```
FLabels: array of TLabel;
```

When you create them:

```
SetLength(FLabels, 5);
for i := 0 to high(FLabels) do
begin
  FLabels[i] := TLabel.Create(Self);
  .......
end;
```

Destroy like this:

```
for i := 0 to high(FLabels) do
  FLabels[i].Free;
FLabels := nil;
```

---

Some general advice for you. When you are faced with a problem, simplify it. Why try to debug object destruction with multiple controls? Create a blank app, and add a single control. Then try to delete that single control. Then move to multiple controls. Don't troubleshoot the complex version, always try to simplify.

Comment: thanks. give please an example. i alredy tried to free all 4 controls.

Comment: "In such a scenario you need to post a message to your form, and then free the button when that queued message is processed." -- Noteworthy: if it's the form itself that needs to be freed, the `Release` method does exactly what you describe.

Comment: i got an error : acces violation at address....
  SetLength(FLabels, 5);
for i := 0 to 4 do
begin
 FLabels[i] := TLabel.Create(Self);
 FLabels[i].Top :=  100+z*i;
 FLabels[i].Left := 88;
......

Comment: Time for you to fire up your debugger and work out what you did wrong. You have the answer to the question that you asked.

Comment: I solved this, but again when i try to frre them, controls remains on form.
 for i := 0 to high(FLabels) do begin
  FLabels[i].Free;
FLabels := nil;
end;

Comment: That code is wrong. See if you can spot how it differs from mine. You are setting FLabels to nil inside the loop. I urge you to follow the advice in the final section of my answer. You asked about destroying controls at runtime. Why conflate that with you also trying to learn how to use arrays. One problem at a time.